# How to improve this loop so that the result will appear when the data sets are large?

Tags: r, loops

The following code belongs to part of the project I am working on, the issue is that it will only run for small sets of data, but does not return result when the data set is large (due do complexity and work). How can I improve my code so that it will be more efficient?

```
if((systemToUse == "Preference Points" && riding == "all")){
riding <- 1
seatsOfLiberal <- 0
   seatsOfCpc <- 0
  seatsOfNdp <- 0
  seatsOfGreen <- 0 
  ballots <- as.list(GetPointsBallotsFromFile(kPointsFilename)[[as.integer(riding)]])
  while((riding + 1) <= length(as.list(GetPointsBallotsFromFile(kPointsFilename)))) {
    for(i in 1:length(ballots)){
      ballots[[i]] <- as.integer(unlist((strsplit(ballots[[i]], "\\ "))))
    }
    winningParty <- (PreferencePoints(ballots))[[1]]
    if(winningParty == "LIBERAL"){
      seatsOfLiberal <- seatsOfLiberal + 1
    }
    if(winningParty == "CPC"){
      seatsOfCpc <- seatsOfCpc + 1
    }
    if(winningParty == "NDP"){
      seatsOfNdp <- seatsOfNdp + 1
    }
    if(winningParty == "GREEN"){
      seatsOfGreen <- seatsOfGreen + 1
    }
    riding <- riding + 1
    ballots <- as.list(GetPointsBallotsFromFile(kPointsFilename)[[as.integer(riding)]])
  }
  seatsIncorrectOrder <- c(seatsOfLiberal, seatsOfCpc, seatsOfNdp, seatsOfGreen)
  seats <- NumOfBallotsCorrectOrder(seatsIncorrectOrder)
  PrintCountryResults(seats)
  }
```

## yesno_ballots_small.txt

Yes No Ballots
Riding 1
YES YES NO NO
NO YES NO NO
YES NO YES NO
NO NO NO NO
YES YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO YES YES
YES YES YES NO
NO YES NO NO
NO NO NO NO
NO NO NO YES
NO NO NO NO
NO NO NO NO
NO NO NO YES
NO NO NO NO
YES NO NO YES
YES NO NO YES
YES YES YES NO
YES YES NO YES
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO

Riding 2
YES YES NO YES
NO NO YES YES
YES YES YES NO
NO NO NO YES
YES YES YES NO
YES YES NO YES
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES YES
NO NO NO NO
NO YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES NO NO NO
YES YES NO NO
YES YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES NO NO
YES NO NO NO
YES NO NO YES
NO NO NO YES
YES YES NO NO
YES YES NO NO

Riding 3
NO NO NO NO
NO YES NO YES
YES YES YES YES
YES NO YES YES
NO NO NO NO
NO NO YES YES
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO YES YES
NO NO NO NO
NO YES NO NO
NO YES NO YES
NO NO YES YES
NO YES NO YES
NO NO YES NO
YES NO NO YES
NO YES NO NO
YES YES NO YES
NO NO YES YES
YES YES YES NO
NO NO NO NO

Riding 4
YES YES NO YES
YES YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES NO NO
YES NO NO YES
YES YES NO NO
NO YES YES YES
NO NO NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
NO YES NO NO
YES YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES NO NO YES
YES YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO

Riding 5
YES YES YES NO
NO NO NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO YES NO
NO NO NO NO
YES YES NO NO
NO YES NO NO
NO YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES NO NO
NO NO YES YES
YES YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES YES
NO NO NO NO
NO NO YES YES
NO YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO YES NO
YES YES YES NO

Riding 6
NO NO YES YES
YES YES NO NO
NO NO YES YES
NO NO NO NO
NO NO YES NO
YES NO NO YES
YES YES NO NO
NO NO NO NO
NO NO NO NO
NO NO YES YES
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO YES YES
YES YES NO NO
YES YES NO NO
NO YES NO NO
YES YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO NO NO
NO NO YES YES
NO NO YES YES
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
NO YES NO NO
NO YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO NO NO

Riding 7
NO NO YES YES
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
NO YES NO NO
NO YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES NO YES
NO NO NO NO
YES YES NO NO
YES YES NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES NO NO
NO NO NO YES
YES YES YES NO
NO NO YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO NO YES
NO NO NO NO

Riding 8
NO NO YES YES
YES YES YES NO
NO NO NO NO
NO NO YES YES
NO YES NO YES
YES YES YES YES
NO YES YES YES
NO NO YES NO
NO YES NO YES
NO NO NO NO
YES YES NO NO
NO NO NO NO
NO NO YES YES
YES YES NO NO
NO NO NO NO
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO YES NO
YES YES NO YES
YES YES YES NO
YES YES YES NO
NO NO YES YES
NO NO NO NO
NO NO YES NO
YES NO NO NO#
four in a line, the big one is simillar just with more ridings

Comment: Do you have an example small dataset and large dataset with which to test your function with? It's hard to test the function without data including `systemToUse` and `riding`.

Comment: I think you attempted to attach a dataset, but it just appeared as mostly YESs and NOs. What I was hoping for was _code_ containing the data, ideally edited into your post instead of a separate attachment.